# All Outputs Going to Zero MNIST NumPy Solution with Simple Neural Net

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to just use NumPy to get a simple, relatively accurate digit-reading neural net. My code runs and gets the right MNIST digit information, but ends up giving the same result of predicting each digit to be unlikely to fall in any of the 10 digit classes.

I think my error has to be somewhat basic. Is there a huge issue with not having thresholds? Are my datatypes messed up? Anything to point me in the right direction would be hugely appreciated; I've been staring at this and tweaking stuff for hours.

Here is a link to my code on GitHub: https://github.com/popuguy/ai-tests/blob/master/npmnistnn.py

And here's a paste:

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

def display_mnist(img, label):
    '''Visually display the 28x28 unformatted array
    '''
    basic_array = img
    plt.imshow(basic_array.reshape((28,28)), cmap=cm.Greys)
    plt.suptitle('Image is of a ' + label)
    plt.show()

hidden_layer_1_num_nodes = 500
hidden_layer_2_num_nodes = 500
hidden_layer_3_num_nodes = 500
output_layer_num_nodes = 10
batch_size = 100
dimension = 28
full_iterations = 10

def convert_digit_to_onehot(digit):
    return [0] * digit + [1] + [0] * (9 - digit)

images = mnist.train.images
# images = np.add(images, 0.1)
labels = mnist.train.labels
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def slope_from_sigmoid(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

syn1 = 2 * np.random.random((dimension**2, hidden_layer_1_num_nodes)) - 1
syn2 = 2 * np.random.random((hidden_layer_1_num_nodes, hidden_layer_2_num_nodes)) - 1
syn3 = 2 * np.random.random((hidden_layer_2_num_nodes, hidden_layer_3_num_nodes)) - 1
syn4 = 2 * np.random.random((hidden_layer_3_num_nodes, output_layer_num_nodes)) - 1
testing = False
test_n = 3
for iter in range(full_iterations):
    print('Epic epoch bro, we\'re at #' + str(iter+1))
    for section in range(0, len(images), batch_size):
        if testing:
            print('Syn before',syn1)

        training_images = images[section:section+batch_size]
        training_labels = labels[section:section+batch_size]
        l0 = training_images
        l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0, syn1))
        l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1, syn2))
        l3 = sigmoid(np.dot(l2, syn3))
        l4 = sigmoid(np.dot(l3, syn4))
        l4_err = training_labels - l4
        l4_delta = l4_err * slope_from_sigmoid(l4)
        l3_err = np.dot(l4_delta, syn4.T)
        l3_delta = l3_err * slope_from_sigmoid(l3)
        l2_err = np.dot(l3_delta, syn3.T)
        l2_delta = l2_err * slope_from_sigmoid(l2)
        l1_err = np.dot(l2_delta, syn2.T)
        l1_delta = l1_err * slope_from_sigmoid(l1)
        syn4_update = np.dot(l3.T, l4_delta)
        syn4 += syn4_update
        syn3_update = np.dot(l2.T, l3_delta)
        syn3 += syn3_update
        syn2_update = np.dot(l1.T, l2_delta)
        syn2 += syn2_update
        syn1_update = np.dot(l0.T, l1_delta)
        syn1 += syn1_update
        if testing:
            print('Syn after',syn1)
            print('Due to syn1 update', syn1_update)
            print('Number non-zero elems', len(syn1_update.nonzero()))
            print('Which were', syn1_update.nonzero())
            print('From the l1_delta', l1_delta)
            print(l0[0:test_n])
            print("----------")
            print(l1[0:test_n])
            print("----------")
            print(l2[0:test_n])
            print("----------")
            print(l3[0:test_n])
            print("----------")
            print(l4[0:test_n])
            print("----------")
            print(training_labels[0:test_n])
            a=input()
            if len(a) > 0 and a[0]=='s':
                testing=False
correct = 0
total = 0
l4list = l4.tolist()
training_labelslist = training_labels.tolist()
print('Num things', len(l4list))
for i in range(len(l4list)):
    print(["{0:0.2f}".format(a) for a in l4list[i]])
    # print(l4list[i])
    # display_mnist(l0[i], str(l4list[i].index(max(l4list[i]))))
    if l4list[i].index(max(l4list[i])) == training_labelslist[i].index(max(training_labelslist[i])):
        correct += 1
    total += 1
print('Final round', 100*(correct/total),'percent correct')
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. If there's any structure to it I fail to see it. Please split the code into functions, with descriptive names, of no more than ~25 lines. Each function should perform a single task, and the function should only be dependent on its inputs. Create a `main()` function that calls the other functions to accomplish your task (no code at the outermost level).  Once you've converted your code, please write test-functions that test each function (i.e. `def test_foo(): ...` to test your `def foo(...): ..` function) - check that you get the output you expect from a range of inputs.

Comment: Questions of the type "why is this code not working?" are not a good fit for SO, and will quickly be closed. If you go through the steps in my previous comment, you should be able to come back with a proper question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In any case, "staring at this and tweaking stuff for hours" isn't a debugging technique that is likely to get you anywhere.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway guys. I basically got frustrated because I wrote something closely resembling another piece of code I had written which worked and the same thing solved using TensorFlow. I thought maybe a neural net expert could look at it for 30 seconds and see a glaring flaw. I'll make my code more functional and try to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperparameters in this instance were just improperly tuned. Bringing down the number of nodes per hidden layer to 15 and changing the learning rate down to 0.1 yields a significant performance increase.